# Calling a number on the iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

So,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel: 14165551212"]];
```

calls a phone number on the iPhone.
What other things can we do, though? *I'm trying to make a simple app that has a list of phone numbers. It dials the first one in that list, and re-dials if it is engaged.* Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly open a link in Safari. It should also be possible to go to the Mail app and create an email. I heard that you can also go to the Messages app.

And, I don't think that what you described is possible. Your app can't do much from the background. And I'm pretty sure that it can't control/monitor any other apps(including Phone), so it will not be possible to re-dial it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is partially possible starting with iOS 4.0 and even better with iOS 5. You may initiate dialling a number from your app with telprompt URL schema and when iOS finishes with the call it will open your app again, see [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028329/ios-4-2-return-to-app-after-phone-call/10635015#10635015)

What is problematic is getting the result of the call: whether it was successful or engaged, etc. You may want to have a look at CTCallCenter class reference.