# IPhone: How to start a call and then get back to my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 4.2 - Return to app after phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028329/ios-4-2-return-to-app-after-phone-call)

I want to give user a chance to call somebody directly from my app. That's why I use this code:

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0801920"]];
```

I't works just fine, but the problem is that I want that after call is finished or if user press cancel it cames right back in my app. Now it just stays in calls of the phone. What I need is to use some kind of delegate.

I was googling and I came up with something like these:

```
    pinkAppDelegate *appDelegate=  (pinkAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

But I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this. The open URL call will open a different application. The current running application is the receiving application of the openURL method. That application is now the foreground application and it wont be able to re-launch your application.