# Can I return to a mobile site after a phone call from a tel link?

Tags: mobile, tel

I have a mobile site where the user can call someone via a tel link. I'm looking for a way to bring them back to the mobile site after the call ends. I've found solutions for [native Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i) and [native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028329/ios-4-2-return-to-app-after-phone-call?lq=1) but not for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to this question is no, [tel: URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) do not support any way of taking visitors back to your website after the call has ended.