# Is there a way to use GSM gateway to make a call?

Tags: ios, swift, gsm, gateway

I know one way to make a call. It is something like this:

```
private func facetime(phoneNumber: String) {
    if let facetimeURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "facetime://\(phoneNumber)") {
        let application: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if (application.canOpenURL(facetimeURL)) {
            application.openURL(facetimeURL);
        }
    }
}
```

And I know about VoIP [SIP client](http://www.portsip.com/voipsdk.html). But is there another way to make a call which uses GSM gateway inside my app on a device without jailbreak?

Comment: do you want system to call , or your application to call and handle all call related stuff ?

Comment: @ogres I need just make to call with using the sim card in my app. I can handle incoming calls already.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22049335/334402