# iOS detect action from UITextView with phone number being tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

iOS 7 and XCode 5.

I have a textview with a phone number that can be touched to make a call.
I have implemented the UIGestureRecognizer with a selector, but this "doesn't work" (more on that below)

The issue is this:
When I tap on the phone number on the device I get an alertview prompt "(phone) Cancel/Call"

Here's what I want to do:
I want to capture (for data collection purposes, not real behavior) whenever the user pushes the "call" button in the alertview.

The reason why the UIGestureRecognizer "doesn't work" is because the selector method only gets called if the user taps on the cancel button or taps on the phone link multiple times. Both of these cases are useless for me.

Any suggestions?

Note: I dont want to make a button to place the call since by doing this the OS takes me back to the phone app after the all instead of my app, like the textview does.

Comment: Nobody? That sucks...

Comment: Based on your last point, there is a way to force the OS to go back to your app after a phone call. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635015/2410991

Comment: Thanx, I actually stumbled upon telprompt:// before, but there are comments online that this option is not documented by Apple (I can't find a doc about it either) therefore Apple may reject apps with it or they may remove this option in future updates.
Even then, I can't seem to capture the "Call" button from this either though